# How to mock day.js using testcafe to click on calender

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to click on a calendar using test cafe with today's date, I tried using moment to get the date format but not able click on calendar, I'm using selector (withText), it always returns no selector found.

Comment: Would you please clarify your exact question? Is it 'how to mock a library', 'how to click the calendar', or 'why the selector returns nothing'? What kind of calendar are you using? What approaches have you tried? What does your test code look like?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Alex Skorkin how to click on the calender was my question? Developer uses day.js wrapper, I tried to use classes but they are having dynamic values and it's not recognizing the selector.
//

     await t.click(this.btnDate);
     var selected_date = moment();
     var output_pattern = "dddd, MMMM D, YYYY"; 
     var todayDate = selected_date.format(output_pattern);
     await t .expect(this.test.getAttribute('aria-label')).contains(todayDate);
     await t.click(this.test.withText(todayDate));

//

Also please post an example how to click day.js

Comment: Sorry, but this information is still not sufficient for us to see the issue. Could you please provide a simple example or a public link to the calendar that you are using?

Comment: @Artem thank you https://www.phila.gov/the-latest/archives/#/?templates=featured this  url has the sample date picker, I'm not using similar one but I would like to know how it works for this one

Answer (score 1):

Example for https://www.phila.gov/the-latest/archives/#/?templates=featured

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Select date`
    .page `https://www.phila.gov/the-latest/archives/#/?templates=featured`

test('Select date', async t => {
    const dateInput = Selector('input[name="start"]');

    await t
        .click(dateInput)
        .click(dateInput.parent('.vdp-datepicker').find('.cell.day').withText('2'))
        .expect(dateInput.value).eql('May. 02, 2020');
});
```